# imagemagick font metrics -- how to place a text in a grid?

Tags: shell, imagemagick, fontmetrics, mvg

let's have a look at the following image:

[image]

I have a horizontal grid and i want to place a text in this grid. The above example is wrong, because what i would like to have is that each character is placed exactly in one of the cells of the grid.

I wonder, if i can adjust the text-output in imagemagick to achieve this, *without* having to place each of the characters with it's own command.

Some additional facts:

- i am using imagemagick from some shell script
- i am doing rather complex drawings with imagemagick's MVG -- so it would be nice if the text could be still placed with the MVG commands
- i am able to adjust the width of the grid by a few pixel, if this would be required with your solution, but all cells of course need to have the same width
- i am always using the same fixed-width font (Courier) for this
- i am able parse the font-metrics in my shell script and use this information to apply values to my text-commands
- i only care about horizontal placement, vertical placement is not important because i render each row individual

With all this in mind -- is there any solution for my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the kerning option - setting inter-character spacing.

e.g.

```
for i in 0 3 6 9 12 15
do
    convert -kerning $i -font Courier -pointsize 24  label:":Kerning $i:" label_$i.jpg
done
```

will generate the following images. You must simply find the right kerning value for match the grid. (for monospaced font - like your Courier)

[image]

Comment: this is indeed very interesting -- i will have a look at it, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a non mono-typed font that you want to force into a grid, you can use this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm test*png

font=~/Library/Fonts/WittenbergerFrakturMTStd.otf
gridsize=32x32

chr() { 
   case "$1" in
      64 ) echo '\@' ;;
      92 ) echo '\\' ;;
      *  ) printf \\$(printf '%03o' $1)
   esac  
}  

for i in {32..127}; do
   c=$( chr $i )
   echo -n "$c: "
   convert -background transparent -density 90 -pointsize 12 -gravity center -font "$font" label:"$c" -extent $gridsize test-$i.png
done

convert test-{32..127}.png +append test.png
```